# Does the rank-nullity theorem apply to linear transformations on sequences?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the linear transformation, $T:V \rightarrow\ V$, where $V$ denotes the space of infinite sequences of real numbers, $T(x_0,x_1,x_2,...)=(0,x_0,x_1,x_2,...)$.

Then $ker(T)=${0} since $x_0,x_1,x_2,...=0$ in order to get the zero sequence. From this, I would have assumed that $im(T)=V$ from the rank-nullity theorem, but yet, $(1,x_0,x_1,x_2,...)\not\in image(T)$

As a side question, our textbook tells us to find if a linear transformation (in which the domain and codomain have the same dimension), by first checking if $ker(T)=${0}, and if it's not clear, to then check if $image(T)=V$ (target space). Here, I saw that the kernel's dimension was 0, so I thought that it was an isomorphism, (which it turns out, isn't true). How should I have gone about solving this then?

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem deals with linear transformations on finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: What do you want to "solve"?

Comment: I am just wondering why the rank-nullity theorem isn't 'working' or if I'm messing/missing something, and how should I go about checking if linear transformations on sequences are isomorphisms or not

Comment: @Fred I missed that detail, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fred observed in the comments, the Rank-Nullity Theorem applies to finite-dimensional vector spaces. Indeed, for any map from an infinite-dimensional vector space to itself the kernel is infinite-dimensional and/or the image is.

You've already observed that $T$ is not even bijective, e.g., there is no ${\mathbf v} \in V$ with $T({\bf v}) = (1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, so a fortiori it's not an isomorphism.

**Remark** On the other hand $T$ (like any linear map) induces an isomorphism $\widetilde T: V / \ker T \to \operatorname{im} T$, and in our case $V / \ker T \cong V \cong \operatorname{im} T \cong V$, so via those isomorphisms $\widetilde T$ can be identified with an isomorphism from $V$ to itself.